# how to reload pdf and preserve same position file (in emacs)?

Tags: emacs, auctex, viewers

I would like to view pdf files in emacs, and when I reload them from disk I want to be at, more or less, the same position in the new file as I was in the old one.

I am viewing these with the bundled "DocView" (is there something better?)

Maybe there is a solution combining bookmarks and DocView?

aside: I decided to make this a TeX question because there it lots of emacs support here, and it's really the only time I find myself obsessively compiling, reloading and viewing pdfs - and I expect I'm not the only one!

Comment: how about using a `pdf` viewer that doesn't need to be closed in the first place? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that DocView does do this, and I hadn't noticed before!  So for the record:

Viewing a pdf in DocView, the key-command

```
g
```

queries you to reload the pdf from disk, and (in the situations I tried) keeps you at the same location after the buffer is reverted.  The command that is invoked is doc-view-revert-buffer

Comment: This is very simplistic!